# Angular 7 point images to cdn

Tags: angular

How can I change all `<Img src='./assets/abc.svg'>` to `<Img src='cdn.example.com/abc.svg'>`? Basically I want to transform the image sources.

I am aware of `--deployUrl` and `baseHref` options but those things seem to not transform imgs' `src` attribute. Please see this as well: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6666

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do it with command line arguments, I don't know if it exists already. But you can do it programatically using pipes.

```js
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

@Pipe({
    name: 'env',
})
export class EnvPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(url: any): object {
        return environment.production ? /*do transformation here*/ : url;
    }
}
```

and in you template

```html
<Img src={{'./assets/abc.svg' | env}}>
```

Drawback is to add this pipe in all your urls (with risk of being forgeted)

Comment: I am aware of this option but I don't really want to add `env` to every single image in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read this:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-editable-config-files/
You can create two json (dev and prod) with 'assetsUrl' properties to distinct the values.
In dev environment it will load './assets', in prod 'cdn.example.com' And don't forget to use `[src]` instead `src`